# Best settings to rasterize vectors in QGIS

Tags: qgis, rasterization

[image]

[image]

I set 20*20 for my resolution, but the result just ran as below pixel size (the pixel size just become 3734.611609999999928,-4489.000505000003614). I just have no idea how to fix it. Below link is the data I used.

[Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dTglFrIxzR8e-cjsKu8PdGOIMjSkjSvt?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tampered with the projection / coordinate system of the input layer in any way?

Comment: The name of the option in the user interface seems to be misleading. By looking at the command that gets generated, the values are transferred into target size https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html#cmdoption-gdal_rasterize-ts, not into target resolution https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html#cmdoption-gdal_rasterize-tr

Comment: I exported the layor to change the CRS system. It's kinda weird because  I used the other computer to run and it just succeeded.

Comment: Thank you guys for replying!

Comment: Do you mean that you do not have any problem now?

Comment: See also the answer to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/465895/rasterize-vector-to-raster-resolution/465922#465922 that explains the difference between "pixels" and "georeferenced units" when selecting the "output raster size units".