# Rasterize (vector to raster)_Resolution

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I have been trying to use "Rasterize (vector to raster)" tool but I am a bit confused in the rationale of defining the Width/Horizontal resolution & Height/Vertical resolution with respect to: Pixels or Georeferenced Units.

Comment: Do you have a specific task you are trying to solve?

Comment: Yes ...rasterizing a road network vector layer

Comment: The QGIS user interface is a bit fuzzy. "Width" and "Horizontal resolution" are two things with different meanings. Width is used when the unit selection is Pixels, Horizontal resolution is used when the unit seelction is Georeferenced units. The text "Width/Horizontal resolution" fools users to think that it describes one thing that has two alternative names.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of Pixels vs. Georeferenced units is documented in https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#gdalrasterize but it may still be a bit confusing.

When selecting Pixels as Output raster size units, the input values (for example 10,10) will be converted into "target size" `-ts` parameter of the gdal_rasterize utility. The command will create an image that is 10 pixels wide and 10 pixels high.

```
gdal_rasterize -l layer_name -burn 0.0 -ts 10.0 10.0 -a_nodata 0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff path_to_data_file C:/Temp/processing_Gzyoxx/34f9f363f25640c1901a6d78edd7aa44/OUTPUT.tif
```

If the unit selection is Georeferenced units then the values will be converted into "Target resolution" `-tr` parameter. The command will create an image that has a pixel size of 10x10 georeferenced units (for example meters). The size of the image in pixels (width and height) is large enough the cover the source vectors with the 10x10 unit pixels.

```
gdal_rasterize -l layer_name -burn 0.0 -tr 10.0 10.0 -a_nodata 0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff path_to_data_file C:/Temp/processing_Gzyoxx/2c10fdbb007b4414ab636cf343afbee7/OUTPUT.tif
```

Parameters `-ts` and `-tr` are also documented in https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html#cmdoption-gdal_rasterize-ts and https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html#cmdoption-gdal_rasterize-tr.